# Calculate Probability Using Random Variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I found the following question in my text-book:

A bus comes in a delay which is uniform between $0$ and $10$ minutes.
Daniel comes $3$ minutes before the bus is supposed to arrive the earliest.

1. Calculate the possibility that Daniel waits more than $6$ min.

**My solution:**

Let $X$ be a random variable that describes the delay of the bus, we know that $X\thicksim\operatorname{Uni}(0,10)$ and that for sure he will wait at least $3$ min so we calculate $P(X>3)$:
$$P(X>3)=\int_3^\infty f(x)\,dx.$$
Now we can replace $\infty$ with $10$ since $f(x)=0$ for $x>10$ (Probability density function) thus getting $7/10$.

2. In a specific day Daniel woke up late and arrived to the bus station in a delay of $4$ minutes.
   What's the possibility he missed the bus?

Daniel will miss the bus if it arrived in the first $4$ minutes so:
At first I though this is the same as
$$\frac{P(x<4\mid x=4)}{P(x=4)}=\frac{0}{P(x=4)}=0.$$
But It's clearly wrong and doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You established $X$ to be a random variable that describes the time Daniel waits for the bus, which is not the best choice here, because it does not follow a uniform distribution between $0$ and $10$.

For example, in the original settings, Daniel comes $3$ minutes before the bus is supposed to arrive the earliest, so the probability for him waiting more than $6$ min should $P(X>6)$ instead of $P(X>3)$.

However, in the second question, he indeed came to station of $4$ min late, so what does the event $X=4$ mean? It means the bus came $4$ min later than Daniel, i.e., the bus came in totally $4+4=8$ min late. Of course this does not make sense at all. In fact, in your setting, the probability should read $P(X\geq 0)$. If Daniel did not miss the bus, then the waiting time for him should be non-negative.

You should set $X$ to be the time for such bus come in a delay, which ranges uniformly from $[0,10]$. Then the first one is $P(X>3)$ and the second one is $P(X<4)$. If $X\geq 4$, then the bus came later than Daniel, so he would not miss the bus.

Comment: For 2 please suppose that I changed X to be the delay for the time

Comment: Your calculation in 1 is correct. I think you just confused the time that the bus delayed with the time Daniel waited. As for 2, I have mentioned in my answer: $P(X<4)=0.4$. Daniel missed the bus iff the bus came in a delay of less than $4$ mins,

Comment: For the second one shouldn't it be a Conditional probability? Since the question says given that daniel wake up 4 mins late... and I learnt that when we see "given" then use Conditional probability

Comment: This is true, but in this problem, the time of delay and the time Daniel came to the station are **independent**. Whenever Daniel arrived the station, the delayed time for the bus follows uniform distribution between $0$ and $10$. Thus, we do not need to use conditional probability here. Or more precisely, the conditional probability reduces to the single probability for the bus because of the independence.

Comment: Thank you, can we chat for 1 min? I have a general question about definition (Something I didn't understand from my text-book)

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to start a chat...

Answer (score 2):

For 1) you need to calculate $P(X>6\mid X>3)$ since we know he will wait at least 3 minutes.

For 2) We can safely assume that the probability of him arriving 4 minutes late is independent of the arrival time of the bus, so we get $P(X<4\mid \text{4 min late})=P(X<4)$

Comment: What if I change X to be the delay for the time then my calculations in 1 are right?

Comment: @MrCalc X is the delay/time he waits — so we know he is waiting at least 3 mins - so we get (4/10) / (7/10) = 4/7 which is not 7/10

Comment: If we make the change I suggested then the answer should be 7/10 because notice that daniel comes 3 min before the first time the bus can even arrive at

Comment: @MrCalc not sure — the definition of X leaves it ambiguous to me.

Comment: @MrCalc ah, ok — so “delay” is relative to some fixed bus schedule — in that case yes, you are correct for (1) :-)